# Select the option based on value

Tags: jquery

M trying to do some DOM manipulation where I want to select the dropdown option based on the value :

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("select[name*='weight_prefix']").each(function() {
    $(this)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

Here it's selecting based on the index, How do I do it based on value, for example 
 select the option where `value is '+'`

```
   <select name="product_option[0][product_option_value][0][weight_prefix]" class="form-control">
       <option value="=">=</option>
       <option value="+">+</option>
       <option value="-" selected="selected">-</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `val()` :

```js
$("select[name*='weight_prefix']").val("=");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="product_option[0][product_option_value][0][weight_prefix]" class="form-control">
  <option value="=">=</option>
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-" selected="selected">-</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any jQuery for this. Just go with plain simple vanilla Javascript and set the `value` of the `select` element:

```js
document.querySelector('[name="product_option[0][product_option_value][0][weight_prefix]"').value = "+";
```

```html
<select name="product_option[0][product_option_value][0][weight_prefix]" class="form-control">
  <option value="=">=</option>
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-" selected="selected">-</option>
</select>
```

If you have more than one (which your selector and using each() suggests), here you go:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('[name*="[weight_prefix]"')].forEach(x => x.value = "=")
```

```html
<select name="product_option[0][product_option_value][0][weight_prefix]" class="form-control">
  <option value="=">=</option>
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-" selected="selected">-</option>
</select>


<select name="product_option[0][product_option_value][1][weight_prefix]" class="form-control">
  <option value="=">=</option>
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-" selected="selected">-</option>
</select>

<select name="product_option[0][product_option_value][2][weight_prefix]" class="form-control">
  <option value="=">=</option>
  <option value="+" selected="selected">+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
</select>
```

- `document.querySelectorAll('[name*="[weight_prefix]"')` gets you a `NodeList` (similar to an `Array`) containing the matched `select` elements.
- `[...document.querySelectorAll('[name*="[weight_prefix]"')]` pulls your `NodeList` members into an actual `array` (this is called *rest spread*, a feature introduced with **ECMAScript 2015** (also known as **ES6**)), so you can use the Array-method `forEach()` on the `NodeList` to iterate over the list.
- You pass an arrow function to `forEach()`: `x => x.value = '='` (which is almost the same as writing `function(x) { x.value = '=' }`).